# Agregar plantilla para email , ya definida en .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, cshtml

Estoy enviando un correo al usuario que olvido su contraseña, el email ya puede ser enviado, pero quisiera agregar una plantilla personalizada. No se si fuera posible pasarle la vista .cshtml como parametro del cuerpo al email.

Ya tengo una plantilla .cshtml definida, y creo que si yo incluyera el código html en el controlador no se vería bien, pues serían muchas lineas de código.

```
 // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        //Verify Email
        //Generate Reset Password link
        //Send Email
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            // if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "El correo es invalido");
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }


            var emailService = new EmailService();


            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            string Body = "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", Body );

            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);


    }
```

en esta linea mandamos como parametro el body del email

> string Body = "Please reset your password by clicking here";
>               await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", Body );

Espero su ayuda . Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución de la siguiente manera

```
  // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "El correo es invalido");
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            //En esta parte mando a llamar el método CreateBody que servira para pasar la plantilla personalizada, ya creada en .cshtml al email que se le enviara al usuario
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Restablecer Contraseña", CreateBody(model.Email,callbackUrl) );

            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        return View(model);


    }
```

Este es el método que se manda a llamar

```
    //Pasar archivo Email/Index.cshtml para enviar plantilla por email.
    //Recibe el parametro del email del usuario y el link para restablecer contraseña.
    private string CreateBody(string email, string link)
   {
        string body = string.Empty;
          //Esta es la ubicación de la plantilla personalizada ("~/Views/Email/Index.cshtml")
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Email/Index.cshtml") ))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //en la plantilla .cshtml en el lugar que agregaria el email le 
       // agrege {fname} y el lugar del link para restablecer contraseña{flink}
       //remplaza {fname} con el email y {flink} con el link, que son los parámetros que le asigne al metodo
        body = body.Replace("{femail}",email);
        body = body.Replace("{flink}", link);
        return body;
   }
```

Este es una parte de la plantilla que envie por correo. Le removi los estilos para no ingresar tanta información.

```
<tbody>
     <tr>
         <td >
              <div>
                    // aqui va el correo 
                   <h2 >¡Hola {femail}! </h2>
                    <br />
                    <h4 >
                           Haga click en el siguiente enlace para restablecer tu contraseña. 
                    </h4>
                     <h4>
                       //aqui va el link
                         <a href="{flink}"> Click para restablecer la contraseña </a>
                    </h4>
               </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

en teoría podes enviarle un string html, con esto quiero decir que deberías renderizar la vista en primera instancia, hace tiempo use un nugget para esto , no se si hay alternativas modernas [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionMailer)

Hay un ejemplo de como usarlo en el foro de asp net

[https://forums.asp.net/t/1879299.aspx?Asp+Net+MVC4+Pass+View+to+use+it+as+email+templates](https://forums.asp.net/t/1879299.aspx?Asp%20Net%20MVC4%20Pass%20View%20to%20use%20it%20as%20email%20templates)

Básicamente en el controlador de la vista que quieras enviar pones el código para el render (o podes crear un controller genérico de emails y heredar los que quieras implementar)

```
public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    try
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

y en la llamada del mismo

```
    public ActionResult SendMail()
{
    // Get your Model Object
    var model = new MyViewUser();

    var output = this.RenderViewToString("~/Views/Controller/SendEmail.cshtml", model)
}
```

Comment: Hola, trate de utilizar tu código pero no me funciono ya que me mandaba un error y no supe como solucionarlo. Lo pude solucionar de otra manera.    Pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda :) . Saludos <3